# Trying to figure out a fluid css layout

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a website with fluid layout, but im having some problems doing so. I want to create a page with 2 columns like this:

http://migo.no/random/css_layout.jpg

Basically I want the left column to have a minimum width of 700px, and stretch out as much as it can, and the right column to have a fixed width of 400px. Also if the window size is smaller then 1100px, I want the scrolling to pop in.

I just cant seem to get it as I want..

Regards,
Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. This results in proportional widths, though. If you want the sidebar to always be 400px and only the main column to expand, I think you could do that by just using min-width.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>

.container {
  width:100%;
  min-width:1100px;
overflow:auto;
 }

.main {
  width:63.63636363%;
  min-width:700px;
float:left;
}

.sidebar {
  width:36.36363636%;
  min-width: 400px;
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic set up in JSBin --------> [HERE](http://jsbin.com/ofinum/edit#html,live)

Basically you simply float the side content to the right The surrounding #container div ensures the two columns will remain at 1100px minimum.

Comment: This is perfect as long as the column contents doesn't span beyond the height of the window. CSS really needs a better solution for this type of layout.

Comment: You can easily add overflow properties to handle more data. Not really sure what you mean...

Comment: If you have a lot of content in either column, the content will flow beyond the bottom edge of the containing column unless you set `overflow-y` to `scroll`, in which case you potentially have a separate scrollbar for each column. To make a block element span the height of the window unless the window height is less than the height of its contents, you need javascript.

Comment: But what if the lengthy content is in the other column? http://jsbin.com/akebij/edit#html,live

Comment: If both sides need to grow then faux columns are your best choice. (http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)

Answer (score 0):

Give your `body` a `min-width: 1100px`, your `#left-column` a `float: left`, `width: 100%` and `margin-left: -400px`, and your `#right-column` a `float: right` and `width: 400px`. Unfortunately, getting your columns to span the height of the window unless it's shorter than their contents will require a javascript resizing function on the `onload` and `onresize` window events. Here's a jsfiddle with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dAgdx/.

(NOTE: the javascript evaluation of the column heights may require some tweaking in different browsers. You may notice that their heights are slightly greater than the window height when resized.

Answer (score 0):

Working example: http://labs.siku-siku.com/experiment/01

**CSS:**

```
#box {
    min-width: 1100px;
}
#left,
#right {
    min-height: 500px;
}
#left {
    margin-right: 400px;
    min-width: 700px;
    background-color: #0f0;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="right">400px fixed width</div>
    <div id="left">min-width of 700px</div>
</div>
```